# Apache poi conditional formatting

Tags: java, apache-poi

My offline excel has already conditional formatting applied to each and every cell of of sheet.
now I am trying to insert a row between already inserted row,but while shifting row the conditional formatting is not getting shifted.

e.g:- I want to insert row between 9 and 10,10th row has conditional formatting attached,now while shifting 10th row shifted to 11th,keeping 10th row empty but the conditional formatting did not get moved to 11th row it being attached to new 10th row only and in 11th row its showing empty conditional formatting

My code

```
private XSSFRow copyRow(XSSFSheet worksheet, int parentRowNum, int destinationRowNum) {
        // Get the source / new row
        XSSFRow newRow = worksheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);
        XSSFRow parentRow = worksheet.getRow(parentRowNum);
        try {
            int nFirstRow = destinationRowNum;
            int nLastRow = worksheet.getLastRowNum();
            int nNumToShift = 1;
            //If the row exist in destination, push down all rows by 1 else create a new row
            if (newRow != null) {
                worksheet.shiftRows(nFirstRow, nLastRow, nNumToShift);
            }
            int nNumOfCell = parentRow.getLastCellNum();
            int nFirstDstRow = nFirstRow + nNumToShift;
            int nLastDstRow = nLastRow + nNumToShift;
            for (int nRow = nFirstDstRow; nRow <= nLastDstRow; ++nRow) {
                final XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(nRow);
                if (row != null) {
                    String msg = "Row[" + row.getRowNum() + "] is Shifted row. ";
                    for (Cell c : row) {
                        ((XSSFCell) c).updateCellReferencesForShifting(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        newRow = worksheet.createRow(nFirstRow);
        newRow.setHeight(parentRow.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < nNumOfCell; i++) {
            XSSFCell oldCell = parentRow.getCell(i);
            if (null != oldCell) {
                XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);
                newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newRow;
}
```

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? For me, using `apache poi 4.1.1`, `XSSFSheet.shiftRows` does taking conditional formattings into account. See [XSSFSheet.shiftRows](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l3019).

Comment: using poi 4.1.0,XSSFSheet.shiftRows is available in 4.1.0 also.Is there is some problem with updateCellReferencesForShifting?

Comment: Just tested, exact your code works for me using `apache poi 4.1.0` too. It shifts the conditional formatting. Not clear where your problem is. Maybe you could upload a sample `Excel` file somewhere. This file should be the source file and it should produce your problem after using shift rows.

Comment: its a simple excel file with three row and three column with conditional formatting,my excel version is Micorsoft office Professional  plus 2013,in my case  reading the conditional formatting from poi is showing zero value tried below code                                                                                       
    XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1"); 
  CTConditionalFormatting[] conditionalFormattingArray = worksheet.getCTWorksheet().getConditionalFormattingArray();                            here conditionalFormattingArray is coming zero

Comment: As said, works for me using `apache poi 4.1.0`.

Comment: Which version of excel you are using?I am not able to read the conditional format available in excel using poi

Comment: My excel have the conditional formatting referring to the other sheet cell reference e.g: - A1 of Sheet 1 have conditional formatting as ='Sheet2'!A1.simliary applied to three row and three column and tried shift row.Doesn't works for me!!!

Comment: Conditional formatting formulas having references to other sheets are available only since `Excel 2010`. The `Office Open XML` which `apache poi` supports, is the one of `2007`. So it does not support those settings. It only supports `conditionalFormatting ` but not the extended  `x14:conditionalFormatting`. There is no general solution for such problems. Maybe there is a special solution. But for this we would need the exact  `Office Open XML` of the extended  `x14:conditionalFormatting` used.